# Pivoting DataFrame on multiple columns and calculating percentage values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to pivot a data frame on multiple columns and calculate the percentage values for the "demand_qty" column. However, the code I'm using doesn't seem to be working as expected.

**Test data**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

dates = pd.date_range(start='2023-06-01', periods=7, freq='D')
countries = ['CountryA', 'CountryB']
products = ['ProductX', 'ProductY']

demand_qty = np.random.randint(1, 20, size=len(dates) * len(countries) * len(products))
shipped_qty = np.random.randint(1, 20, size=len(dates) * len(countries) * len(products))

# Create random test data
data = {
    'date': np.repeat(dates, len(countries) * len(products)),
    'country': np.tile(countries, len(dates) * len(products)),
    'product_category': np.tile(np.repeat(products, len(dates)), len(countries)),
    'demand_qty': demand_qty,
    'shipped_qty': shipped_qty
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Here's what I want to achieve:

Pivot the DataFrame based on the "country" and "product_category" columns.
Use the "demand_qty" column as the value to calculate the percentage.
Each value in the resulting pivoted data frame should represent the percentage of demand quantity for each combination of country and percentage of product share for product category.

**Current code**

```
weekly_sum_df = df.groupby(['country', 'product_category', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W-THU')]).sum().reset_index()

pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(weekly_sum_df, index='date', columns=['product_category', 'country'], values='demand_qty', aggfunc=lambda x: np.mean(x) / x.sum() * 100)
pivot_df
```

However, the resulting data frame doesn't show the percentage values as expected.

**Expected output**

```
date,       CountryA, CountryB, ProductX, ProductY, demand, shipped
2023-06-01      47.5      52.5      53.9       46.1    282    267
```

Note : - The genrated shippd / demand values are random therefore in the test data sometimes shipped value is more than demand  ;)

Could you please guide me on how to correctly pivot the DataFrame and calculate the percentage values based on the "demand_qty" column for each combination of "country" and "product_category"?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I *think* I understand the question. Could you please post an example output to demonstrate how it relates to the posted input? Do I understand correctly that you want on each row, the percentage of demand that has been shipped on each date, aggregated by country and aggregated by product?

Comment: Hi, no. The expected output is presented in the comment. It's the % share of demand per country  and same % share of demand per product. shipped is just one extra metric

Comment: On date `2023-06-01`, CountryA and CountryB have 4 combined entries for ProductX (and nothing else). CountryA demands 7,11 and CountryB demands 15,8. `(7+11)/(7+11+15+8)` is 43.9%, which I don't see in the example output. Could you please explain the math that I'm missing?

Comment: in the current code, we are converting it into weekly data so 2023-06-01 is basically all week put together :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this work around.
I had to create one dataframe per information (percentage by country, percentage by product, total) and then concat them in a final one.

```
COLS_GB = ["product_category", "country"]

df_weekly_sum = (
    df[["date", "demand_qty"]].groupby([pd.Grouper(key="date", freq="W-THU")]).sum()
)
df_weekly_sum.rename(columns={"demand_qty": "demand_qty_weekly"}, inplace=True)
dfs = [df_weekly_sum]
for col in COLS_GB:
    df_gb = (
        df[[col, "date", "demand_qty"]]
        .groupby([col, pd.Grouper(key="date", freq="W-THU")])
        .sum()
        .reset_index()
    )
    df_gb = df_gb.merge(df_weekly_sum, left_on="date", right_index=True)
    df_gb["percentage"] = df_gb.demand_qty / df_gb.demand_qty_weekly
    df_col = pd.pivot_table(df_gb, index="date", columns=col, values="percentage")
    df_col.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    dfs.append(df_col)

df_final = pd.concat(dfs, 1)
print(df_final)
```

**---------- EDIT -------**

In order to have only one row, add the `closed` and `label` arguments in your grouper, like this :
`pd.Grouper(key="date", freq="W-THU", closed="left", label="left")`

Comment: Hi, Thanks but we have 2 errors, It's generating 2 rows, but we should get only 1 for THU as 01/06/2023 was a Thursday? secondly, the % values are not matching the basic excel calculation for the product as shared in question (expected output).

Comment: Hi,
I edited my answer. I think it will work ?

Comment: yes, works. Thank you!